# Updating tab on tabstrip on view show

Tags: jquery, kendo-mobile

I can't get this simple piece of code to work. What am I doing wrong? What I want is the tab to change when I navigate to this view.

```
<div id="foo" data-role="view" data-show="changeTab">
  <div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="tabstrip">
      <a href="#foo" data-icon="contacts">foo</a>
      <a href="#bar" data-icon="contacts">bar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
function changeTab() {
  var tabstrip = app.view().footer.find(".km-tabstrip").data("kendoMobileTabStrip");
  tabstrip.switchByFullUrl("#bar"); //activate second tab
}
</script>
```

Or try it here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jositako/8FgLf/)

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI Mobile TabStrip is updated automatically when navigation to a View with the Tab's URL occurs. No need for additional code in this case. Check the modified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRV8U/1/).

```
<div id="foo" data-role="view">
  <div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="tabstrip">
      <a href="#foo" data-icon="contacts">foo</a>
      <a href="#bar" data-icon="contacts">bar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bar" data-role="view">
  <div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="tabstrip">
      <a href="#foo" data-icon="contacts">foo</a>
      <a href="#bar" data-icon="contacts">bar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
</script>
```

As per your answer - if you have several Views with one Url, you can use the select method to navigate manually to the new View, which will correctly select the tab. Check the new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRV8U/15/).

Comment: That is helpful and good to know. How about if the view itself has a different id, for example a view with a id="new" and I want the tab to change to #bar from #foo?

I have a view that could belong to either tab foo or bar depending on the some JSON data it loads.